# android application title in application manager

Tags: android, title

I want to change my app name from "com.myapp" to "MyApp"(this title is showing in the android app manager).

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean: You want to see 'MyApp' as your app's title in App Manager?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `android:label` attribute in your manifest for your `<application>` and `<activity>` elements.  What is it set to?

- [Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#label)
- [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label)

Comment: Thank you, it seems that I had the label in the <manifest> tag and not in the application tag and activity tag..

Answer (score 1):

how about [setTitle(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28int%29) or [setTitle(CharSequence title)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

Answer (score 0):

I did all the above and it did not work for me. The problem was that my style had the option to have no title bar enabled but I did not specify it in the style.  What eventually worked is below :
Steps:

- Edit res/values/style

```js
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> 
        </style>
```

and it works